# Voximplant: Get record URL

Tags: voximplant

I am trying to make outbound call with:

```
 call = VoxEngine.callPSTN(number, caller);
 //call1: event incoming alerting call +573202336398
 //call2: newly created outgoing call  +13213627981
 VoxEngine.easyProcess(e.call, call);
```

How can I get record url when the disconnect event appears?
It works with the event RecordStarted, but with event RecordStopped it's showing me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a global scope variable and later on obtain the url from RecorderEvents.Started.

```
let url = "", recorder;

recorder = VoxEngine.createRecorder({ hd_audio: true });
recorder.addEventListener(RecorderEvents.Started, (ev) => {
    url = ev.url;
});
call1.sendMediaTo(recorder);
call2.sendMediaTo(recorder);
```